# How to prevent a specific .animate() from running via a seperate jQuery script

Tags: jquery, buddypress

Okay, so specific question... In BuddyPress's global.js we find this...

```
/* Textarea focus */
jq('#whats-new').focus( function(){
    jq("#whats-new-options").animate({
        height:'40px'
    });
    jq("form#whats-new-form textarea").animate({
        height:'50px'
    });
    jq("#aw-whats-new-submit").prop("disabled", false);

    var $whats_new_form = jq("form#whats-new-form");
    if ( $whats_new_form.hasClass("submitted") ) {
        $whats_new_form.removeClass("submitted");   
    }
});
```

What I am concerned with is the animations. I'd like to cancel them completely via a seperate jQuery file ( so as not to mess with BuddyPress's files ). I've tried duplicating the lines and using variations of .stop(), .stop(true), and even .clearQueue() but without resolve. Is there a way to either cancel the event out or prevent it entirely? Let me also add that I have a separate script running that autosizes the textarea when it's being used, this is why I do not want the adjustment nor do I want to restrict the size of the textarea. The problem I'm running into is, as the global.js instructs, when the user clicks outside of the textarea ( blur ) and then re-clicks in the textarea ( focus ) the textarea is, once again, resized to 50px.

Comment: I would remove the attached event listeners for the `focus` event from the `textarea`.

Comment: I just tried... $('#whats-new').focus().off(); but it does not prevent the event.

Comment: It has to be `$('#whats-new').off('focus')`

Comment: Thank you for the correct usage. I've tried it but still the event is firing. The animation runs and the textarea is resized. :\

Comment: Assuming your code is running, then you call you `off()` before the other code is called. You need to make sure your `off` Is called after that code. Another thing you could try is to listen `once` to the `focus` remove the listeners at that time and then attach your regular listener. That way the animation will only run for the first focus.

Comment: That sounds good. Would you happen to have an example of how to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Parris, Have you tried .finish() method?
 .finish() is called on an element, the currently-running animation and all queued animations (if any) immediately stop and their CSS properties set to their target values. All queued animations are removed.

Comment: That's the thing. I do not want the effect at all. I don't want the textarea to be resized by this event.

Answer (score 0):

Could you overwrite the style for the element in css using the important rule, or even add a class with this style. This should ensure all elements with the id you are trying to keep at 40px will not be resized.

```
#whats-new-options {
  height: 40px !important;
}
```

You could also look at using the jQuery [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method to remove the event from the element.

Comment: I'm attempting to remove the event as I have a script running to autosize the textarea while it's being used. The problem I'm running into is that if the user clicks outside of the textarea and then reclicks it ( thus reapplying focus ) the textarea readjusts the size to 50px, based on the BuddyPress global.js's instruction. This is why I'm attempting to remove the event entirely.

Comment: Have you tried the the jQuery [unbind method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the event from the element. Still I would have thought using CSS to ensure the textarea always remains at 40px would eliminate having to remove the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
jq('#whats-new').unbind('focus')
```

This will remove the `focus event` from `jq('#whats-new')`

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this myself. My not working code...

```
$('#whats-new').focus(function(){ $('#whats-new-options').stop(true); $('form#whats-new-form textarea').unbind('focus'); console.log('focus'); });

$('#whats-new').blur(function(){ $('#whats-new-options').stop(true); $('form#whats-new-form textarea').unbind('blur'); console.log('blur'); });
```

(I added the console log to test) I found that, for whatever reason, the first line (focus) was never firing but the second line (blur) works fine. So I modified the code to this...

```
$('#whats-new').blur(function(){ $('#whats-new-options').stop(true); $('form#whats-new-form textarea').unbind('focus blur'); });
```

Works as intended now tho I'm still not certain as to why the focus line simply refused to fire.